# Warning while Building maven project in multiple thread

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to build my maven project in parallel multithread using the command

```
mvn -T 1C install
```

but I am getting below warning and the thread in building in single thread. I have checked the documentation for this plugin but i am not getting any help

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that have goals not marked   *
[WARNING] * as @threadSafe to support parallel building.                  *
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in Abs Microservice Analytics:
[WARNING] org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE
[WARNING] Enable debug to see more precisely which goals are not marked @threadSafe.
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
```

Comment: Can you file an issue? Nothing wrong should happen but it's better to take care of those warning messages

Comment: First I would recommend to use an more recent version of the plugin ...and afterwards I would file in an issue...

Comment: I hope its just a normal nickname... Did you file a  bug ticket? If so can you post the number here?